# Why are my Fragments appearing on top of each other?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have a main layout of this form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And I am doing FragmentTransaction calling `.replace()` on both of them to invoke two Fragments that use the following XML:

Fragment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="true">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Why are the two fragments appearing on top of each other? I want Fragment1 to appear directly above Fragment2, which has a RecyclerView.

Edit: Replacement code:

```
fragment1 = Fragment1.newInstance();
fragment2 = Fragment2.newInstance();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment1, "fragment1");
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment2, "fragment2");

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Or am I doing this wrong and I should be using something other than replace?

Comment: Show your code on how did add Fragment and include also a screenshots to make it more clear.

Comment: @Enzokie Added some code

Comment: Call transaction one-by-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you put two layouts inside `CoordinatorLayout`. `CoordinatorLayout` behaves like `RelativeLayout`. Try this instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: If it is like RelativeLayout it didn't seem to let me do the whole "layout_above" or "below" thing, is that correct?

Comment: Your fix worked btw, can you explain more how that works?

Comment: I mean it behaves like `RelativeLayout` but not inherent from it. It is used for different purpose.

Comment: @KaliMa Basically, all the elements inside `CoordinatorLayout` do not have a arrangement but just on top of each other. You should checkout `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout` and `FloatingActionButton`. Then, you will know that the content should be inside a single element.

Answer (score 0):

You can import fragments directly to activity's layout:

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.packacge.Fragment1"/>

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.packacge.Fragment2"/>
```

Comment: Yes but later I may want to swap out for other fragments in those areas; right now I am just trying to get this two-case to work